# Moving in a linear direction based on touch input in Unity 2D

Tags: javascript, c#, touch, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble in unity 2D. I am trying to make a ball move in a linear direction across the screen after detecting a single touch, however this is proving quite difficult. I have researched and researched but I cant seem to find the answer to both parts of the problem, hence I come here. I apologise if this was not the right thing to do. Anyways, on to the question. How would I detect a single touch and how would I move a game object on the X axis for a certain number of coords. I don't want a touch direction specified, it just needs to be a touch. Another thing could be a touch on the object itself. Sorry again if I wasn't meant to do this. P.S. my code is terrible and barely even there, so I wont share it.

Answer (score 0):

To detect touch you use [Input.GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html). The number in the parameter is the number of the touch, like the first, or the second or the third touch, etc... If you just want one touch, just use `Input.GetTouch(0)` all the time.

To move the object in the X axis you need to user [Transfrom.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html). The parameters are the amount you want to move in a specific axis.